# Selecting DropDownBox Value using GECKOFX Webcontrol VB.net

Tags: html, vb.net, geckofx

Im beating my head against the wall - someone please help.

Using IE webbrowser i simply used the following.

collection as htmlcollection = htmldoc.getelementbytagname("select")

```
for each ele in collection
  dim options = ele.children
'some if thens to match the option to the option i need selected
ele.setattribute("value",optionselectedbyuser)
```

All this worked great, it set the value and selected it in the webpage dropdownbox.  Now that the website requires Firefox i have to redo my coding and the drop down boxes are killing me  this is what i have tried

```
 dim collection as gecko.geckoelementcollection =htmldoc.getelementbytagname("select")

     for each ele as gecko.element in collection
        'some if thens to make sure im in the correct dropdown control
            for each child in ele.childnodes
              'using this to obtain the options of the dropdownbox and make sure it matches what user has selected, if it does i assign the element that value
                 if child.textcontent.tostring.toupper = inputfromusertoselect.toupper then
                    ele.setattribute("value",child.nodevalue("value"))
                 end if
             next
      next
```

After assigning the value, i reread the outerhtml code and the value i set is now in the html but on the webpage the actual item isnt selected.  I also notice in the outerhtml there is an option tag with its own value.  Im wondering if this is where i need to set the value but i cant seem how to assign the value of the options. see outer html

```
  <select selected="selected" value="Detached" id="GarageType" name="GarageType" class="required"><option value="">-- Select Garage Type --</option>
          <option id="GarageTypeNone" value="None">None</option>
          <option id="GarageTypeAttached" value="Attached">Attached</option>
          <option id="GarageTypeDetached" value="Detached">Detached</option>
          <option id="GarageTypeCarport" value="Carport">Carport</option>
          <option id="GarageTypeBuiltIn" value="Built In">Built In</option></select>
```

as you can see in html code, i have already set the value to "Detached" and by trouble shooting i set the selected =selected. but to no avail it still doenst change value on page.  What am i doing wrong with geckofx!!!HELLLP

Answer (score 1):

Tested in Visual Studio 2013 - VB.NET:

```
Dim el1 As Gecko.DOM.GeckoSelectElement = _ 
    GeckoWebBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByName("GarageType")(0)

el1.Options.item(<NUMBER>).Selected = True
```

Sorry, code only answer since I do not speak English.